# Big o notation of n^100+2^n

Tags: big-o

What is the meaning of [image: formula] ?.

I found this in the question bank and the answer was [image: formula2].
That doesn't make sense to me because n^100 grows much faster than 2^n (I used demos to make sure)

Comment: No, 2^n grows faster. Exponential functions grow faster than polynomials. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55468/how-to-prove-that-exponential-grows-faster-than-polynomial

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, but when I draw the graphs, n^100 is growing faster, I am not sure if there will be intersection between the 2 functions on the long run, and also I couldn't prove it mathematically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow's scope is limited to questions about *writing code*. Mathematics, statistics, and theoretical computer science all have their own, distinct Stack Exchange sites (none of which, to be clear, I'm actively asserting this question to be fit for; would need to read their individual rules).

Answer (score 3):

2^n grows faster than n^100 (at very large values of n, precisely n>996) so it's O(2^n). You could prove it with limits using L'Hopital's rule. Exponentially bounded functions are a super set of polynomially bounded functions.